# Create multiple DIVs using jQuery and pass values to functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm adding multiple DIVs via jQuery with an onClick() event. But `function rTxt(mndt){` doesn't seem to be working. Can someone hep to fix this?

```
var tDV = 0;
$("#aTx").click(function() {
    var diagonalScl;
    var txSiz;
    tDV++
    $('#ltn').append('<div id="aTextDV"+tDV class="ui-widget-content"></div>');
    $('#aTextDV'+tDV).append('<div class="txrsPos" id="rzTx" onclick="rTxt(this)"><img src="img/markers/welcome.png"/></div>');
    $("#aTextDV"+tDV).append('<textarea rows="3" id="aText">Your Name</textarea>');

    function rTxt(mndt){
    $("#"+mndt).resizable({
        alsoResize: '#aText'
        ,
        create: function(event, ui) {
            diagonalScl = diagonalSwItms();
            txSiz = parseInt($("#aText").css("font-size"));
        },
        resize: function(e, ui) {
            var diagonalSclNw = diagonalSwItms();
            var ratio = diagonalSclNw / diagonalScl;            
            $("#aText").css("font-size", txSiz + ratio * 10);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
onclick="rTxt(this.id)"
```

you are passing the `Element` object to function instead of its `id`

Comment: Nope! that did not solve the issue. The SRc is not working either. Also do you see something wrong with the closing of `function rTxt(mndt){` ?

Comment: probably you are missing the closing brace `}` of your `rTxt` function